# How to set LinearLayout content with respect to GridView or GridView content with respect to LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-gridview

I want to align LinearLayout contents with respect to gridview. The gap between the day(i.e Sun,Mon..etc) in the following calendar layout should be equal to gridview space(1,2..30). Background image for the day should be avoided.

**Layout code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_right" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Sun"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Mon"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Tue"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Wed"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Thu"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Fri"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Sat"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/black"
            android:numColumns="7"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Add one more property to your GridView is android:gravity="center"
2. GridView item layout should something like below

//  GridView Item layout XML
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
     <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried that but no changes.